# Error "The primary key column of type 'DateTime' cannot be generated by the server."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a composite primary key (Int and DateTime) on one of my tables. When I try to add a new record using LINQ (with the DateTime field set to "AutoGeneratedValue = true", and getdate() as default value on the server), I get the following errors:

> The primary key column of type 'DateTime' cannot be generated by the server.

Any idea why this is? I believe it has worked before but I can't make out what would cause it to stop working. Unfortunately there is little specific information about this kind of error.

Also, manually committing a row through SQL Server Management Studio works fine and is correctly autogenerating the datetime value.

**Edit - Got it working - Must be a bug in LINQ to SQL**: I got it working if I set "IsPrimaryKey" for the DateTime to false within the DBML while keeping the composite key on the database side.

So this works:

- SQL Server: Composite Primary Key (Id INT, MyDate DATETIME - AUTOGENERATED)
- DBML: Mark **only** Id as Primary Key. Mark MyDate as Autogenerated, but **not** as Primary Key.

I think that's a bug in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: If you're in a position to be able to, I'd suggest running SQL Profiler against the server and capturing the queries Linq is generating - this may shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the default of the field in SQL Server to self-generate. For DateTime fields this is normally `GETDATE()`.

Edit:

Apart from `AutoGeneratedValue = true` you also need to set `Auto-Sync` to `OnInsert`.

Comment: That's actually the case already. Adding it to my question description.

Comment: @Alex - did you set `Auto-Sync` to `OnInsert` as well?

Comment: @Oded, no I didn't, but I've never had to set Auto-Sync to OnInsert to get the desired auto generating of a value on a server and not getting exceptions within LINQ...

Comment: @Alex - how often had you used a composite key in these situations?

Comment: @Oded - didn't use it in a composite scenario so far; however, I tried AutoSync OnInsert and it still throws the same error.

Comment: @Alex - sorry, I am out of ideas :(

Comment: @Oded - thanks for trying man... This is really mystifying me :(